# What cryptography primitives/concepts, other than the basic ones, does Monero use?

Tags: cryptography

The following are the "basic" cryptography primitives/concepts, taught in all beginner textbooks on cryptography:

- symmetric encryption (stream and block ciphers. AES, etc.)
- asymmetric public-key encryption (RSA, elliptic curves, discrete logarithm)
- digital signatures
- hash functions
- MACs
- key establishment

Can you list **all** the cryptography primitives/concepts used by Monero that are **not** taught in these beginner textbooks? I already know of two:

- Ring signatures
- CryptoNight

What are **all** the others?

Comment: Note: "Ring signatures" -> "Traceable Ring signatures"

Comment: @JonathanCross Do you mean that Monero uses only "traceable ring signatures", and that there are such things as "non-traceable ring signatures", which Monero does **not** use?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of different [Ring signature schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature#Applications_and_modifications) and "ring signatures" usually refers to the non-traceable type.  The "traceable" part may sound confusing at first, but here we are talking about [Double-spend protection in CryptoNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#Double_spending_protection), not the ability to track / observe user payments (as is done in Bitcoin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pedersen Commitments and Range Proofs

See https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt

Comment: Is this a comprehensive list or are there some others?

Comment: I think that's all of them.